# AWS S3 copy fails with PutObject operation: Access Denied error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have an S3 bucket that has the following attributes:

- publicly accessible
- bucket owner-preferred object ownership
- ACL enabled

I have a bucket policy as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy12345",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt6789",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I use access key and secure access key credentials to authenticate upload requests.

I am able to copy files to `my-bucket` in my region of interest (`us-west-2`).

Another colleague on the east coast of the US is also able to upload files with these credentials.

A second colleague in Europe is not able to upload files (error described below).

All three of us are using the same credentials (using `diff` to verify our configurations are identical).

We are all using very similar versions of the AWS CLI kit.

The European colleague gets the following error copying a file up to the bucket with `--debug` enabled:

```
...
2023-06-14 21:23:33,157 - ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0 - botocore.parsers - DEBUG - Response body:
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>PMC4DBQYJHHHR6AN</RequestId><HostId>93pDbtMDY5cFKBWUn7gU6Wf92fSSw+y97gNiL3oIG5CaT/iNP/Qwei2LPWG00heTdT3C6WsMVDI=</HostId></Error>'
2023-06-14 21:23:33,165 - ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0 - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event needs-retry.s3.PutObject: calling handler <bound method RetryHandler.needs_retry of <botocore.retries.standard.RetryHandler object at 0x116568690>>
2023-06-14 21:23:33,165 - ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0 - botocore.retries.standard - DEBUG - Not retrying request.
2023-06-14 21:23:33,165 - ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0 - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event needs-retry.s3.PutObject: calling handler <bound method S3RegionRedirectorv2.redirect_from_error of <botocore.utils.S3RegionRedirectorv2 object at 0x116548d10>>
2023-06-14 21:23:33,165 - ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0 - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event after-call.s3.PutObject: calling handler <function enhance_error_msg at 0x111b5b4c0>
2023-06-14 21:23:33,165 - ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0 - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event after-call.s3.PutObject: calling handler <bound method RetryQuotaChecker.release_retry_quota of <botocore.retries.standard.RetryQuotaChecker object at 0x1165494d0>>
2023-06-14 21:23:33,166 - ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0 - s3transfer.tasks - DEBUG - Exception raised.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "awscli/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 139, in __call__
  File "awscli/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 162, in _execute_main
  File "awscli/s3transfer/upload.py", line 758, in _main
  File "awscli/botocore/client.py", line 341, in _api_call
  File "awscli/botocore/client.py", line 697, in _make_api_call
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
...
```

Is the `s3:PutObject` action required in the bucket policy? The east coast user is able to upload files without it. One major difference is the geographic location of the third person. Could this create a timestamp issue for the HMAC authentication token?

Is there anything else I need to set or enable to allow anyone else to add items to the bucket (given the right private credentials) regardless of physical location/timezone?

Comment: I think some of you in the US might be assigned to another group where you have access to upload files to the S3 bucket. The mentioned policy clearly states that it's allowed only to read the files. So, if you include the `s3:PutObject `, it would resolve the problem.

Comment: Is that documented anywhere? I'd like to know what I'm doing is correct and has no unintended side effects. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: the mentioned policy seems common for all the users and that's why the policy contains only the read access. In order to upload the files to the bucket, either you can include your European counterparts in your other group. or you can create a new policy and assign to them for [uploading](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html) files into the mentioned bucket. Also, refer to this link for [S3PolicyVsIAMPolicy](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/iam-policies-and-bucket-policies-and-acls-oh-my-controlling-access-to-s3-resources/)